# i want to create a Files class to read dynamic json in spring boot

Tags: json, database, spring-boot, jhipster, nested-json

as u can see bellow, a `json` script of the Files, `FQCN` and `Jparser` classes that I want to create in my domain. U notice here that the keys of Files, `FQCN` and Jparser Objects are dynamic. Could u help me please to create the classes in the domain so the I can write my `json` data to a `database`?

```
{
    "**Files**": {
      "monolith/daytrader-ee7-web/src/main/java/com/ibm/websphere/samples/daytrader/web/TradeServletAction.java": {
        "packagex": "com.ibm.websphere.samples.daytrader.web",
        "importx": [
          "java.io.IOException",
          "java.math.BigDecimal"
        ],
        "TradeServletAction": "TradeServletAction"
      },
      "monolith/daytrader-ee7-web/src/main/java/com/ibm/websphere/samples/daytrader/web/TradeScenarioServlet.java": {
        "packagex": "com.ibm.websphere.samples.daytrader.web",
        "importx": [
          "java.io.IOException",
          "java.io.PrintWriter"
        ],
        "TradeScenarioServlet": "TradeScenarioServlet"
      },
      "monolith/daytrader-ee7-web/src/main/java/com/ibm/websphere/samples/daytrader/web/TradeAppServlet.java": {
        "packagex": "com.ibm.websphere.samples.daytrader.web",
        "importx": [
          "java.io.IOException",
          "javax.servlet.ServletConfig"
        ],
        "TradeAppServlet": "TradeAppServlet"
      },
      "monolith/daytrader-ee7-web/src/main/java/com/ibm/websphere/samples/daytrader/web/TradeWebContextListener.java": {
        "packagex": "com.ibm.websphere.samples.daytrader.web",
        "importx": [
          "java.io.InputStream",
          "java.util.Properties"
        ],
        "TradeWebContextListener": "TradeWebContextListener"
      },
    "**Dup_Class**": {},
    "**Version**": "v2.0.0r46",
    "**Enums**": {},
    "**FQCN**": {
      "com.ibm.websphere.samples.daytrader.web.TradeServletAction": [
        "TradeServletAction"
      ],
      "com.ibm.websphere.samples.daytrader.web.TradeScenarioServlet": [
        "TradeScenarioServlet"
      ]},
    "**Jparser**": {
      "monolith/daytrader-ee7-web/src/main/java/com/ibm/websphere/samples/daytrader/web/TradeServletAction.java": {
        "com.ibm.websphere.samples.daytrader.web.TradeServletAction": "TradeServletAction"
      },
      "monolith/daytrader-ee7-web/src/main/java/com/ibm/websphere/samples/daytrader/web/TradeScenarioServlet.java": {
        "com.ibm.websphere.samples.daytrader.web.TradeScenarioServlet": "TradeScenarioServlet"
      }
}
}
```

those are the classes:

```
package com.ref.myapp.domain;


import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import java.util.List;

import jakarta.persistence.ElementCollection;
import jakarta.persistence.Embeddable;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Embeddable
public class **Files** {

    @JsonProperty("filePath")
    private String filePath;

    @JsonProperty("packagex")
    private String packagex;

    @ElementCollection
    @JsonProperty("importx")
    private List<String> importx;

    public Files() {
    }
```

}

```
package com.ref.myapp.domain;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import java.util.Map;

public class **FQCN** {

    @JsonProperty("FQCN")
    private Map<String, String[]> fqcnMap;

    public Map<String, String[]> getFqcnMap() {
        return fqcnMap;
    }

    public void setFqcnMap(Map<String, String[]> fqcnMap) {
        this.fqcnMap = fqcnMap;
    }

// You can add additional methods or functionality as needed
    public FQCN() {}
}

package com.ref.myapp.domain;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import java.util.Map;

public class **Jparser** {

    @JsonProperty("Jparser")
    private Map<String, Map<String, String>> fileMappings;

    public Map<String, Map<String, String>> getFileMappings() {
        return fileMappings;
    }

    public void setFileMappings(Map<String, Map<String, String>> fileMappings) {
        this.fileMappings = fileMappings;
    }

// You can add additional methods or functionality as needed
    public Jparser() {}
}
```